# jQuery issue with angular

Tags: jquery, html, css, angularjs, angularjs-directive

I need help with moving jquery functionality to angular way. I've a jQuery enabled page and following code is used to set the css and toggling.

```
// dropdown option
    var drop= $('#main-wrapper .all-menu-details .dropdown-option');
    drop.hide();

    $(".toggle").click(function() {
        $(this).toggleClass("active");
        $(this).parent().parent().next()
        .slideToggle(300);

        $(this).parent().parent()
        .toggleClass('red');
    });
```

and a button

```
  <div ng-repeat cat in categories>
    <div ng-repeat item in cat.Items>
       <button class="toggle">Option</button>
    </div>
 </div>
```

since this button falls in two nested ng-repeat, the jQuery click is not working.

I can add code for toggling using ng-show, but it does not have effect as jQuery toggling as jQuery also set some css.

Thanks for the help in advance.

By the way I'm using following HTML template 
http://188.226.173.21/takeaway/menu-with-right-checkout.html and I'm trying to toggle Option button.

Comment: Can you be more clear in what the expected outcome should be when you click a button? What's `$(this).parent().parent().next().slideToggle` supposed to be doing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In angular, you would better use `directive` to operate DOM.

```
`<button class="toggle" toggle-directive>Option</button>`
`app.directive('toggleDirective', function(){
   return function(scope,ele, attr){
    ele.click(function() {
    ele.toggleClass("active");
    ele.parent().parent().next()
    .slideToggle(300);

    ele.parent().parent()
    .toggleClass('red');
   }); 
  }});`
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use ".on" function on the container and then specified the selector:

```
$("your container here").on('click', '.toggle', function() {
}
```

Comment: You should not do DOM manipulation in a controller. Thats is what directives are for. Especially if you are trying to do it the "angular way."

Comment: ok, i forgot that the asker said that he want to do that in a "angular way".